# How i can get objects coordinates in result YOLOv8

Tags: coordinates, object-detection, yolov8

from ultralytics import YOLO

## Load a pretrained YOLOv8n model

model = YOLO('best.pt')

## Define current screenshot as source

source = 'screen'

## Run inference on the source

results = model(source)

Results now seems like:
screen 0 (LTWH): 0,0,1360,768: 384x640 3 Accepts, 699.6ms
screen 0 (LTWH): 0,0,1360,768: 384x640 2 Accepts, 718.6ms
screen 0 (LTWH): 0,0,1360,768: 384x640 3 Accepts, 707.6ms

How i can see here coordinates, help please

If u can help me for use pyautogui and moove mouse on this coordinates, will be great =)